# Get-ADDomain | Select Name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am currently making a script which is supposed to go into a server, grabbing the domain name and the Users in a specific group, then go out and continue on the next server. Well, i got the connection phase done and now I need the users and the domain name. Here is a snippet of code:

```
foreach ($User in (Get-ADGroupMember fjärrskrivbordsanvändare | Select Name)) 
{
    $UserArray += $User.name
    $DomainArray = Get-ADDomain | Select Name 

    $DomainArray
    $UserArray
}
```

As you can see I add the Names of the users in an Array, then I want to save the NAME of the domain in an array and then print them both to see if its ok. But when i print the domains, the name does show up ALONG with the ip to the server and some code i dont know where it comes from. It looks like this

```
cstein    (IP) 82ddgfhdghjdfw-sdfgsbbc-42sfdsdf4-a8dfgd-734ddeee345817
```

Does anyone know a fix to this? I only want "cstein" when i do Select Name.

I scrambled all the numbers and letters in the long "code" or whatever it is. I don't know if it's sensitive information.

Keep in mind that you are talkig to a Swedish 15 year old when you write an answer.

Comment: The code looks like a GUID of something. Also, drop `select name` from foreach statement, you need user objects, not just names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `PSCustomObject`containing a `User` and a `Domain` property:

```
$result = Get-ADGroupMember fjärrskrivbordsanvändare | Foreach {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $_.Name
            Domain = Get-ADDomain | Select Name 
        }   
}
```

Now you can retrieve all user names using:

```
$result | select User
```

---

Note: You probably don't want to call `Get-ADDomain` each time within your foreach...

Comment: I'm calling addomain in my foreach because I want the domain of 42 servers in an array. I will try your solution! :)

Comment: Just a quick question, do you want me to create the custom object inside of the foreach? It's very important that i have my users and domains in arrays because I'm exporting the infromation later and i want every name to have the domain name beside it, that way its easy to filter the users you want by company in excel.

Comment: You see, in the csv file I want the delimiter between the user and the domain name on every user. Are you saying i could do something like this? `$result.domain[$row] + $delimiter + $result.user[$row] | Out-File my\file\is\located\here.csv`?

Comment: You can just do this: `$result | Export-Csv 'my\file\is\located\here.csv' -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: And I would get something like this in the CSV-file:    `
Mike;Carlsteins
Jenny;Carlsteins
Simon;Carlsteins
Michael; almer


etc


` But of course expanding down

Comment: When i tried what you said it just simply doesn't work. The export doesn't work and I cant even print the result. And no errors? I'm really confused atm please answer :) Since I'm not at 20 rep yet I can't start a chat. Can you vote something up so we can discuss further in a chat?